# Trying to break a while loop serial readline () function in python 2.7 tkinter using a Button. Reading data from aruduino Mega

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, arduino, serial-port

I am trying break a while loop that prints the serial readline() function in my program. 
I have a quit button set up but this freezes the program when I press it. I am looking for a way to make this QUIT button function properly when I press it.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import serial
from Tkinter import *

ser = serial.Serial('COM4', 9600) # Setting up serial connection

class Application(Frame):
    def feed_data(self):                 # Serial print function
        while True:
            print ser.readline()


    def createWidgets(self):
        self.QUIT = Button(self)         #Quit button
        self.QUIT["text"] = "QUIT"
        self.QUIT["fg"]   = "red"
        self.QUIT["command"] = self.quit

        self.QUIT.pack({"side": "left"})

        self.DATA_READ = Button(self)          # Serial Read Button
        self.DATA_READ ["text"] = "Data Read",
        self.DATA_READ["command"] = self.feed_data

        self.DATA_READ.pack({"side": "left"})

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.createWidgets()

root = Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
root.destroy()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your `createWidgets()` method this way:

```
 def createWidgets(self):
     self.QUIT = Button(self, text='QUIT', bg='red', command=quit)         
     self.QUIT.pack(side=LEFT)    
     self.DATA_READ = Button(self, text='Data Read', command=self.feed_data)  
     self.DATA_READ.pack(side=LEFT)
```

**Note** that according to [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), you need to rename your variables this way:

- self.DATA_READ → self.read_data
- self.QUIT → self.quit

But in order not to confuse yourself or the maintainer of your program, avoid using reserved keywords. This means you need to rename `self.quit` to something like `self.quit_program`